# remove string part using sed

Tags: bash, sed, terminal

Hi I am trying to remove part of string using sed command but looks like all options that i came across stack overflow doesn't seem to work.

```
sub-285345_task-WM_dir-28_epi.nii
sub-285345_task-LANGUAGE_dir-11_epi.nii.gz
```

I want to remove `_task-***` part of it. I want to remove task-**, key value pair.

```
sed s/_task-.*//g
```

This removes even dir-** after task. `sub-285345_epi.nii.gz`

How can i remove only task key value pair?

Comment: See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: You haven't told us what the `***` represents in "I want to remove `_task-***`". Is it the part up to the next `_` or `-` or `.` or something else? [edit] your question to include the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
sed 's/_task-[^_]*//'
```

`[^_]*` will match upto the next `_`.

**Example:**

```
$ sed 's/_task-[^_]*//' <<<'sub-285345_task-WM_dir-28_epi.nii'
sub-285345_dir-28_epi.nii

$ sed 's/_task-[^_]*//' <<<'sub-285345_task-LANGUAGE_dir-11_epi.nii.gz'
sub-285345_dir-11_epi.nii.gz
```

Comment: This is ok when there is only one word between task- and _dir. If there will be a double word with an underscore that would not work. This is IMO safer method: `sed 's/\(_task-.*_dir-\)/_dir-0/'`

Comment: @DawidGrabowski This was to cover OP's example, if they want we can come with a different one. As it stands now, this covers OP's cases very well.

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is greedy.

Try something like

```
$ echo sub-285345_task-WM_dir-28_epi.nii | sed -r 's/_task-.*?_dir/_dir/'
sub-285345_dir-28_epi.nii
```

Comment: `?` is useless. sed is always greedy.

Comment: didn't realize that about sed, just went based off regex tester

Answer (score 0):

The underscore seems to be a delimiter. In that case you can use

```
echo "sub-285345_task-WM_dir-28_epi.nii" | cut -d"_" -f1,3-
```